# How to count rows in a Parse class programmatically in an iOS app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a parse back end for my iOS app. 
I have a parse class called "quiz". How can I read the number of rows in the Parse class, I have to use it in my iOS app?

I am using the following code but xcode is not entering the code block.

```
var cnt = 1
var query = PFQuery(className:"quiz")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if error == nil 
{
// The find succeeded.
print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
cnt = objects!.count
}
else
{
// Log details of the failure
print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")                   
}
}
return cnt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not entering because cnt is always zero? Did you set a breakpoint to test the callback?

Comment: Ok, I just saw, it is entering the block after the code return has been executed, the value of cnt is never reset, is it because it is findObjectsInBackGround? is there a findObjectsinforeground?

Comment: @ParthTiwari It is possible to retrieve the objects synchronously using `findObjects:`. Using that in an app is never recommended because it will block the main thread and cause a poor user experience or worse. It is best that you learn how to handle asynchronous operations.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are limits on the accuracy of 'count' operations above a certain number of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick Answer

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is constrained by the query limitation to return [up to 100 objects by default](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-query-constraints). This limit can be increased, but only to a [maximum of 1000](https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-limitation-and-api-calls-count). Because of this, you cannot rely on `findObjects` and then counting the results.

[Parse has included in the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-counting-objects) a simple way to count the total number of objects for a class or particular query.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    print("Sean has played \(count) games")
  }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
 query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
 query.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
    if error == nil {
           print("Sean has played \(count) games")
    }
}
```

### Detailed Explanation

It should also be noted that due to how costly count operations are, Parse has placed limitations on them

> Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests
>   per minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with
>   more than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your
>   application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters,
>   for example.)

This inaccuracy is not due to the 1000 request object limit. The count query will try to get the total number of records regardless of size, but since the operation may take a large amount of time to complete, it is possible that the database has changed during that window and the count value that is returned may no longer be valid.

The recommended way to handle counts is to essentially maintain your own index using before/after save triggers in cloud code. However, this is also a non-ideal solution because save hooks can arbitrarily fail part way through and (worse) postSave hooks have no error propagation. To add on to this, here is another quote by Hector Ramos from the [Parse Developers Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/1GOv37oTY2k).

> Count queries have always been expensive once you throw some
>   constraints in. If you only care about the total size of the
>   collection, you can run a count query without any constraints and that
>   one should be pretty fast, as getting the total number of records is a
>   different problem than counting how many of these match an arbitrary
>   list of constraints. This is just the reality of working with database
>   systems.

And lastly, to quote the Parse Engineering Blog Post: [Building Scalable Apps on Parse](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/building-scalable-apps-on-parse/).

> Suppose you are building a product catalog. You might want to display
>   the count of products in each category on the top-level navigation
>   screen. If you run a count query for each of these UI elements, they
>   will not run efficiently on large data sets because MongoDB does not
>   use counting B-trees. Instead, we recommend that you use a separate
>   Parse Object to keep track of counts for each category. Whenever a
>   product gets added or deleted, you can increment or decrement the
>   counts in an afterSave or afterDelete Cloud Code handler.

Answer (score 0):

Since the count is retrieved asynchronously, the way to return the count is inside a completion closure instead of using `return cnt`.

Here is an example:

```
func countObjectsWithCompletion(completion: (Int?)->(Void))
{
    var query = PFQuery(className:"quiz")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            completion(objects!.count)
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}

countObjectsWithCompletion { (myObjectCount: Int?) in
    if let cnt = myObjectCount {
        print("count is \(cnt)")
    } else {
        print("error getting count")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work because `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` has a limit on the number of objects it can return. `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` should be used or an index can be maintained by the OP.

Comment: @Russell Thanks for adding that. It's better to use the designated method that you have written. And I'm sure the extra details will be helpful when the OP is ready to move onto bigger fish though at this time they are still learning how to bait their line, figuratively speaking.