# Parse Query not returning all rows

Tags: parse-platform

Code that was previously working is now failing...

I have extracted the following lines from my app to show the problem

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EBInspection"];
[query setLimit:1000];
[query whereKey:@"ParentID" equalTo:@"OdP1ZnYHib"];
NSLog(@"Count = %i", [query findObjects].count);
```

These lines find 34 matching rows in the EBInspection table, however there are 86 rows, which I have confirmed using the Parse dashboard and setting a query.  I have also written the following code to test all rows, and it returns 86!!

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EBInspection"];
[query setLimit:1000];
[query setSkip:2000];
int nIns = 0;
for (PFObject *obj in [query findObjects]) {
    if ([obj[@"ParentID"] isEqualToString:@"OdP1ZnYHib"]) nIns += 1;
}
NSLog(@"count= %i",nIns);
```

Strange indeed.  Looks like some kind of data corruption that messes up the query.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` instead of `findObjects` and then counting the results yourself. Try the following

Objective-C

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query whereKey:@"playername" equalTo:@"Sean Plott"];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The count request succeeded. Log the count
    NSLog(@"Sean has played %d games", count);
  } else {
    // The request failed
  }
}];
```

Swift

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    print("Sean has played \(count) games")
  }
}
```

For more information on count operations [see my detailed explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604012/how-to-count-rows-in-a-parse-class-programmatically-in-an-ios-app-using-swift)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions... I tried your code and it returns the same (incorrect) count.

Since my post, I started getting weird results directly from the Parse dashboard.  I initially get the correct 86 rows on a filtered query, and then after simply clicking a column heading to sort, I get 34 rows.

This lead me the conclusion that it was some type of data corruption problem... So I exported the table (to JSON), deleted the table, and imported... And the problem cleared up!!