# How to get count in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a **Athlete** class in Parse core with sports column as **Array datatype** which contains array of sports athlete play like baseball,football etc. All sports which athlete can choose are stored in a master class named as **AthleteSports**

AthleteSports class data:

- Baseball
- Football
- Hockey

Athlete class data Ex.

- John play ["Baseball", "Football"]
- Ray play ["Hockey","Football"]
- Michael play ["Football"]

So can any one help me with a query which gives count of player sports wise i.e

- Football - 3
- Baseball - 1
- Hockey - 1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Model this using a ***relationship*** rather than an array. This is a classic case of a one-to-many relationship (one Athlete can play many Sports). Once you define the relationship, you can perform a simple count query on the relationship to get your result. See this following: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/one-to-many-relationships--2

Comment: @Russell Thanks a lot for reply.. i got your point but problem in my case is i can't able to change schema, it is a working application and have around 2 web application and an ios version already working on it.. so can you please help me to solve problem with similar structure... Thanks again !

Comment: A simple solution would be to add a number column to each Sport which you can maintain using afterSave hooks in cloud code. This way, whenever an Athlete adds a new sport to their array, you can increment the associated Sport counter and easily query it directly.

Comment: That being said, iterating through each of the array data types for each Athlete will be atrocious and I still highly recommend using a relationship. Changing the schema after releasing to production is certainly a pain, but it is doable and happens all the time. The headaches and problems you run into may only get worse as your app continues to grow as is.

Comment: @Russell I am really understand your valuable advice and you are 100% right But Russel i am not in condition to do any such changes, Please can you help me with Query in such schema like is it possible we can use whereExistIn or whereContain for AthleteSport into Athlete table.. Once i will show it to my client even with a lot of load i can convience him to change schema...

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of behavior you want? It sounds like you want to perform a **count operation** to find the total number of `Athlete` objects which contain a given `AthleteSport`. Does the query just need to return the **number** of Athlete objects, rather than the objects themselves? In the meantime, here's some more background information on count operations that may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604012/how-to-count-rows-in-a-parse-class-programmatically-in-an-ios-app-using-swift/33613672#33613672

Comment: Yes, I need number of Athlete which plays a particular sport.
like Basketball is played by 3 Athlete, FootBall is Played by 5 Athlete and so on..

Comment: Is the array full of `AthleteSport` pointers or just the literal string "Football" and so on? For future reference, please try to make your question as precise as possible and show what work you have already tried. Nobody likes to do someone else's work for them