# Count number of objects in Parse.com array

Tags: parse-platform

I am fairly new to the Parse framework and have been looking to implement a like function in my application. 
I created an array in my table that will contain all the people who like a certain item but to display the number of names in that array I need to count how many objects are in that array? How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before on SO. Please search before posting. See one potential answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604012/how-to-count-rows-in-a-parse-class-programmatically-in-an-ios-app-using-swift/33613672#33613672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in

        if results != nil {

            //Set whatever you want to results.count

        }

    }

}
```

I also recommend watching a tutorial on the basics of Parse as this would help you very much. Hope this helps!