# How to get rows count in Cloud Code in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have tried this code: I keep getting success/error was not called.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Offer", function(request, response) {
var duplicationQuery = new Parse.Query("Offer");

console.log(duplicationQuery.count);
});
```

Then I tried this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Offer", function(request, response) {
var duplicationQuery = new Parse.Query("Offer");
duplicationQuery.count()
{
    success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse.text);
    response.success(httpResponse.text);
    console.log("Row count:   "+duplicationQuery.count);
},
     error: function(httpResponse) {
     console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
     response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status); 
 }
}

});
```

I guess I'm stuck with improper syntax. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You should be using a ***count query*** rather than a normal query and then counting the results. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604012/how-to-count-rows-in-a-parse-class-programmatically-in-an-ios-app-using-swift/33613672#33613672

Answer (score 0):

I would say stay away from count queries as they are inefficient. Simply do a `find` query and get the count using the `length` property of your results.

```
var duplicationQuery = new Parse.Query("Offer");
duplicationQuery.limit(1000); // max limit
duplicationQuery.find().then( function(results) {
    console.log(results.length);
});
```

Also bear in mind that the max number of records you can get in any query is limited to 1000.